# Creating new column in table by matching columns in 2 separate tables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, conditional-statements, compare

I have these 2 tables in R.

```
data1 <- data.frame("Type1" = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"), "Type2" = c("F", "F", "U", "F", "U"), "Value" 
= c(1,2,3,4,5))
data2 <- data.frame("Type1" = c("A", "B", "A", "C"), "Type2" = c("F", "F", "U", "F"), "Number" 
= c(0.1, 5, 100, NA))
```

I would like to compare the "Value" column to the "Number" column by matching columns Type1 and Type2 in both tables (data1 and data2).
data2 is my reference table, so that will always have only 1 combination of Type1 and Type2. But my data1 table will have many different combinations of Type1 and Type2 that may be repeated.

This is what I'd like my desired output to look like, I want it to add a column called "Threshold" to my data1 table that let's me know if the Value column is greater than, less than, equal to, or NA to the Number column.

```
Desired_Output <- data.frame("Type1" = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"), "Type2" = c("F", "F", "U", 
"F", "U"), "Value" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "Threshold" = c("Value is greater than number", "Value is 
less than number", "Value is less than number", NA, "Value is less than number"))
```

Thank you for your help!